# Any way to accept bot json and regular objects in Spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

Is this possible to achive in any way?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String test(@RequestBody Person personJson , Person personRegular){
    Person person = personJson != null ? personJson : personRegular;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But that is not a problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can if you send an json representation of `Person` as POST body it will get bound to personJson, and the request parameters will get bound to `personRegular`, another way could be to send a `id` as a request parameter, populate a `personRegular` module attribute by performing a database lookup, and annotating your personRegular with `@ModelAttribute`

Comment: But how about this consumes = "application/json" if i would like to use both?